# Is there a way to generate an officer docx as a pdf without the use of libreoffice?

Tags: r, pdf, export, officer

Due to the data security rules at my job, I can't install certain applications. I was wondering if there was a simpler way to generate word docs (via officer package) as a pdf before R outputs the document.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in R? I'm generating a bulk of docs using officer and would like to generate them as pdfs as they are being created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use package doconv, see https://github.com/ardata-fr/doconv#convert-a-word-file-to-pdf

```
library(doconv)
to_pdf(docx_file, output = "docx_example.pdf")
```

Note it requires MS Office on the machine!